# How to fetch Id token from the browser after log in using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, oauth, webdriver

How to fetch the access token bearer from the browser using selenium webdriver ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the method getCookie() in your test:

```
let cookies = browser.getCookie();
    cookies.forEach(function(cookie){
        //fetch your properties 
        console.log(cookie.domain);
    });
```